# "push BYTE 0x80" and "warning: signed byte value exceeds bounds" in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

When I try to assemble the following code:

```
push BYTE 0x80
```

NASM displays the following warning:

```
warning: signed byte value exceeds bounds
```

What does this means? Note that values below 0x80 don't cause a warning.

Comment: Try this and see what happens, no promises `push BYTE -128`

Comment: Oh, a second thought; have you looked at the opcodes generated ? Do you get the right hex values ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PUSH imm8` doesn't actually push a byte onto the stack. It pushes *at least* a word, which will be sign-extended from the byte operand. Hence, with an operand of `0x80` you actually end up pushing `0xff80`, `0xffffff80` or `0xffffffffffffff80`, which most likely is what NASM is warning you about.

This is described in [Intel's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html):

> The D flag in the current code-segment descriptor determines the default operand size; it may
>   be overridden by instruction prefixes (`66H` or `REX.W`).
>   The operand size (16, 32, or 64 bits) determines the amount by which the stack pointer is decremented (2, 4 or 8).
>   If the source operand is an immediate and its size is less than the operand size, a sign-extended value is
>   pushed on the stack.